If $\sum a_n$ converges and each $a_n \geq 0$, $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ converges using summation by parts
Edit: my post was marked as a duplicate of this post. The answers to this post are not related to what I'm asking. I am not looking to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, as I mentioned in my post. I'm hoping someone can help me prove the statement using summation by parts.
This is exercise 3.7 in Baby Rudin. I've seen solutions using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and other inequalities, but I want to know if it's possible to prove using summation by parts.
What I've done so far is let $b_n = \frac{1}{n \sqrt{a_n}}$ when $a_n \neq 0$ and $b_n = 0$ otherwise. Then, $a_n b_n = \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$. I proved that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ implies $\sqrt{a_n} \rightarrow 0$ and I know that $A_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k$ is bounded by some $M$ because it's a convergent series of non-negative terms.
For convergence, letting $\epsilon > 0$, I want to find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k = n}^m \frac{\sqrt{a_k}}{n} = \sum_{k = n}^m a_n b_n < \epsilon$ for all $m \geq n \geq N$.
By the partial summation formula, I have $\sum_{k = n}^m a_n b_n = \sum_{k = n}^{m - 1} A_k (b_k - b_{k + 1}) + A_m b_m - A_{n - 1} b_n$.
Because $A_{n - 1} b_n \geq 0$, $\sum_{k = n}^m a_n b_n \leq \sum_{k = n}^{m - 1} A_k (b_k - b_{k + 1}) + A_m b_m$.
Because $A_n$ is bounded by $M$, $\sum_{k = n}^m a_n b_n < M \sum_{k = n}^{m - 1} (b_k - b_{k + 1}) + M b_m = M (b_n - b_m + b_m) = Mb_n$.
This is as far as I've gotten, but I know I'm not on the right track because I have no way to reduce $b_n$ to get $M b_n < \epsilon$, based on the way I defined $b_n$.
Does anyone know if it's even possible to prove this with summation by parts? If so, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

@RDK see the first two lines of the post

See the Dirichlet test, which is, in fact, proved by summation by parts. This appears numerous times on this site.

@TedShifrin How can we apply the Dirichlet test without knowing that $a_n$ is monotonic?

$1/n$ is monotonic?

@TedShifrin If $\frac{1}{n}$ is your monotonic sequence, you need $\sqrt{a_n}$ to have bounded partial sums in order to apply the Dirichlet test. This is true for $a_n$, but not necessarily $\sqrt{a_n}$ (e.g. $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$).

Right you are. I suspect summation by parts does not work. Certainly Rudin does not suggest that it should.
